# I cant install react project on my system with create-react-app as well as with npx create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, npm

If I install react project with `create-react-app` it prints that `create-react-project command doesn't exist`.
If I install react project with `npx create-react-app` it prints that

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "BUY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\8088" as it does not contain a package.json file.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BEST BUY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-16T12_39_07_288Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] failed with code 1'.
```

If I install it in windows folder means as an administrator then it installs but when I import any module  in project it prints'Module not found: Can't resolve

```
react-table-6' in 'G:\git\reactApp\src
Error from chokidar (G:\node_modules): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'G:\pagefile.sys
```

Comment: Uninstall Node from your pc and reinstall Node LTS

Comment: I already did it